# java jackson cannot read objects that are inside an inner object

Tags: java, json, rest, jpa, jackson

im developing a rest api web application using spring boot.
i have a problem when converting my entities into json formate,
my entity **Person** has a list of objects **fournitureOrder**,and that object hase an other object of type **Person** which refer to the previous Entity,and a second object of type **Fourniture** that has a reference to the same list of **fournitureOrder**,this is how it look like :

***Person Entity***

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long personId;
    @Column
    private Integer numeroBureau;
    @Column
    private String nom;
    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<MaterialOrder> MaterialOrders;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<FournitureOrder> FournitureOrders;

    @Column
    private String prenom;
    @Column
    private String cin;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String telephone;
    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Grade grade;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        Person person = (Person) o;
        return personId != null && Objects.equals(personId, person.personId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

}
```

***FournitureOrder entity***

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class FournitureOrder{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long FournitureOrderId;
    @Column
    Boolean isAccepted = null;
    @JoinColumn(name = "fourniture_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private Fourniture fourniture;
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;
    @Column(name = "date_order")
    private LocalDate dateOrder;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        FournitureOrder that = (FournitureOrder) o;
        return FournitureOrderId != null && Objects.equals(FournitureOrderId, that.FournitureOrderId);
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }


}
```

***Fourniture entity***

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class Fourniture {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "fourniture_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long fournitureId;
    @Column
    private String type;
    @Column
    private Integer nombre;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="fourniture")
    private List<FournitureOrder> orders;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        Fourniture that = (Fourniture) o;
        return fournitureId != null && Objects.equals(fournitureId, that.fournitureId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
```

i try to return the object without using jackson but it gives me the same result as jackson :

```
{
    "personId": 102,
    "numeroBureau": 5,
    "nom": "techOne",
    "type": "technicien",
    "prenom": "momo",
    "cin": "X079836253",
    "email": "mimomoon@gmail.com",
    "telephone": "0689765432",
    "grade": "PES",
    "materialOrders": [],
    "fournitureOrders": [
        {
            "isAccepted": true,
            "dateOrder": "2023-01-01",
            "fournitureOrderId": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

im expecting the result to be like the following :

```
{
    "personId": 102,
    "numeroBureau": 5,
    "nom": "techOne",
    "type": "technicien",
    "prenom": "momo",
    "cin": "X079836253",
    "email": "mimomoon@gmail.com",
    "telephone": "0689765432",
    "grade": "PES",
    "materialOrders": [],
    "fournitureOrders": [
        {
            "isAccepted": true,
            "dateOrder": "2023-01-01",
            "fournitureOrderId": 1,
            "fourniture":{
                            "fournitureId": 1,
                            "type": "table",
                            "nombre": 9,
                         }
        }
    ]
}
```

yep it is kind of recursive calling but is there is a way to limit the serialization in the second level of converting.
and thanks .

Comment: Well you put `@JsonIgnore` on the field `private Fourniture fourniture;`, no wonder it does not get serialized. You did this most probably because you had a `StackOverflowError` (due to recursion). The morale here is: do not expose database entities directly, introduce DTOs instead.

Answer (score 0):

well i think the only way that will work is removing the *@jsonIgnore* annotaion form both the **fourniture** and **person** attribute and get the **person** object inside the list of **fournitureOrder** and set it to ***null*** and same thing for the **fourniture** object inside the list of **fournitureOrder** and also set the list of **fournitureOrder** inside the **fourniture** object to null
it's kind of cumbersome code but with that it will cut off the inner relation and redendency between entities.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).